# Anyone know what plant this is? (pink flowers, stalks)

Tags: identification, flowers

This plant is growing in my flowerbeds out front of my house. I haven't been at the house as it's a second home, but I'm not sure what this is. Honestly, I don't even know if it's really a plant/flower or just a weed. Any information would be greatly appreciated!

It initially looks like a bush, but it's actually stalks, as can be seen in one of the pictures.

Thank you in advance!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be *Mirabilis jalapa*, common name four o'clock plant (probably because it opens its flowers in the afternoon). it's not a weed, but they do sometimes seed themselves. Info and image here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirabilis_jalapa

Comment: That was my initial impression, but I've been spending my whole weekend days over there and the flowers have never opened, so I'm just hesitant that they're actually four o'clocks.

Comment: Absolutely 4 O'Clock, and it wants more water and less sun. I have inadvertently let them run amuck in my yard. The reds dominate the white and yellow do I pull a lot of reds out. When you have many ,they will  perfume the yard but not overpowering like gardenia. They are a favorite of humming bird moths .

Comment: The bulbs will winter-over in a favorable location in the ground as far north as zone 5 in the US.

Comment: Awesome, thank you all so much!